# PHP/Laravel date/strtotime for -1 month showing current month

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running into an issue where I am trying to achieve a `count()` between the first and last days of the previous month, and it is showing the current month. I've had this code for 2 months and have not seen this issue yet.

Today is March 29, 2019. Here are the queries I'm asking for in blade:

```
{{date('F')}}                         // returns "March"
{{date('F', strtotime("-1 month"))}}  // returns "March"

// count scripts from last month
$first_day_last_month = date("Y-m-01", strtotime("-1 month"));
$last_day_last_month = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("-1 month"));
{{$doctor->scripts()->whereBetween('prescribe_date', [$first_day_last_month, $last_day_last_month])->count()}}
```

The query returns March's data instead of February's. Is this some misuse of strtotime?

**Edit**

After looking into the duplicate question, I was able to figure out the issue.
Thanks to the accepted answer, I was able to improve my code with Carbon and use the preferred Eloquent syntax with `subMonthsNoOverflow(1)`.

Comment: This always comes up at this time of the month. Let's see who can find the supe.

Comment: Tell me about February 29th of this year?

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking at https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. Depending on which version of Laravel you're using you could also look at using `whereMonth()` and `whereYear()`

Comment: Who voted to reopen this? It is an *exact* dupe.

Comment: @JohnConde I understand that the `strtotime` issue has already been answered in a different question, however, there are at least a couple more ways that this can be handled more elegantly with Laravel i.e. not using `strtotime`. Given the chance I would like to leave an answer incase any one using Laravel comes along.

Comment: @RossWilson You would best be served adding it to canonical question so a;ll of that knowledge is in one place. That's how SO prefers this to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Laravel, why don't you use `Carbon` it is so easy:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()->format('F');
```

-- edited to use `subMonth` instead as @RossWilson mentioned.

Comment: This does not explain what the problem is or how it solves it. Plus this question is a dupe.

Comment: I don't see how the downvote is relevant. It solves the problem. Also makes him use a functionality he's suppose to use.

Comment: You can also use `subMonth()` instead of `addMonth(-1)` :)

Comment: `F` is going to give you what you want though.

Comment: If it were obvious they never would have asked the question in the first place. Plus you do *not* explain why this is occurring or how your code solves that problem. Plus you shouldn't answer questions that are duplicates.